# How to save checkboxes states in android app

Tags: android, checkbox, save

I want to save checkbox state in external storage because I don't want to loose data if I delete the app.
The checkboxes are created in java. This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.lettura;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] lettura = {
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
        };
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        for(int i = 0; i < lettura.length; i++)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setId(i);
            cb.setText(lettura[i]);
            l.addView(cb);
        }
    }
}
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save checkbox state in external storage because I don't want
> to loose data if I delete the app.

There are different ways you can do that but do notice if you delete an app android deletes it data from the storage you can use shared preferences or a sqlite database and create a backup xml file and include this shared preferences or database file. In that case the android saves the files in the google drive of that user and restores it when reinstalled.

But if you're looking to save it in storage then follow this tutorial by **Coding In Flow.**

[Save A File to Internal Storage.- By Coding In Flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcfUkjlL9RI)